# Git - reverting a revert, conflicts

Tags: git

I've made some commits and then reverted them. How do I revert the revert? (After my revert there are other commits on the branch). If I remerge my branch into master I get `already updated` because it already includes all of those commits I suppose.

```
* b1e0603 - other commit 
* f835cec - Revert "" 
* 68ffc84 - Revert ""
* da5795b - Revert ""
* 75ae2a0 - Revert ""
*   4e51f8f - Merge branch 'master'
|\  
| * 58a6fe8 - commit
* |   205f2a2 - Merge branch 'on this branch are my commits that weere reverted'
|\ \  
| |/  
|/|   
| * 425d6f3 - commit
* |   0efc0e9 - Merge branch 'on this branch are my commits that weere reverted'
```

Doing `git revert 75ae2a0` ouputs conflicts. And there are like 10 reverts that I have to run. Should I just revert the merge (205f2a2)?

Thanks!

Comment: The best solution depends on what state you ultimately want to be in. One option might be to create a new branch, cherry pick the commits you actually want, reset `master` to an earlier state, *then* merge your new branch into `master`, essentially abandoning the messy history containing the revert commits.

Comment: Did you push your changes to the public repository? If not then you can rewrite your changes. Otherwise it might be more complicated and may require more revert/merge works

Comment: @AmnonShochot didn't push my changes. if I just open and resave all my affected documents will it be enough? Thanks

Comment: Opening and resaving documents is a completely separate issue from your repository's revision history.

Comment: If you did not push your changes then you can: (1) backup your repo (2) reset/revert your changes (the one simpler for your case) and re-apply the changes you're interested in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the discussion above, as you did not push your changes you can re-write you changes with git reset/revert (depends on your specific case).

You can find some great tutorials about your options here in [Atlassian Git Tutorials](http://www.atlassian.com), and specifically in chapters [Undoing Changes](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes) that discuss your options with git checkout, reset and revert commands, and [Reset, Checkout, and Revert](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/resetting-checking-out-and-reverting) that discusses these command both in commit level and file level.

One recommendation, though - as some of these commands are irreversible I'd recommend you to make a backup of your repo and current commits so in case something will get wrong you will have a backup of your changes.

Comment: also, when reverting there will not be conflicts if you start from the latest one, not from the first one (my mistake)