# Who is `them` and `us` in a `git revert`?

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, git-revert

I can't make sense of who `us` and `them` are in these conflicts during a `git revert`, so I don't really know what's happening here:

```
git revert some_commit_hash
```

Then `git status` shows the following conflicts:

```
deleted by them: path/to/file1.h
both modified:   path/to/file2.h
deleted by them: path/to/file1.cpp
deleted by them: path/to/test_file1.cpp
added by us:     path/to/file3.h
deleted by them: path/to/file4.h
added by us:     path/to/file5.h
```

Who is "us"? Who is "them"?

Update: note that the commit I'm reverting is a very large merge commit.

---

NOT duplicates:

1. because it doesn't clarify who is `us` and `them`: [GIT: How dangerous is "deleted by us" conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42174485/git-how-dangerous-is-deleted-by-us-conflict)
2. because it covers `merge` and `rebase` but NOT `revert`, and git frequently uses the same terms to mean *opposite* things depending on the operation: [Who is "us" and who is "them" according to Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025314/who-is-us-and-who-is-them-according-to-git)
3. because it doesn't mention "us" and "them" - [Git - reverting a revert, conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495708/git-reverting-a-revert-conflicts)

Comment: I don't know this off the top of my head, but it should be simple enough to figure out: 1) `git show some_commit_hash` and look for added/deleted files.  2) Correlate those to the current `git status` (with add/delete reversed because you are reverting).  3) Profit.

Comment: I still think this is a duplicate of [Who is "us" and who is "them" according to Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025314/who-is-us-and-who-is-them-according-to-git) - you should edit that question to include a section on `revert` if different than the others.

Comment: @pkamb, no, see #2 under "NOT duplicates" in my question. I foresaw that one coming.

Comment: @GabrielStaples I think pkamb is suggesting that the question/answer should be updated to make this a duplicate, rather than adding a new answer here.

Comment: @chepner, I see. One problem with doing that, however, is even though I regularly add new answers to questions 6 months to 13 years old ([I've got the "necromancer" badge 26 times](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer?userid=4561887)), most people don't, so editing that question is unlikely to cause it to ever receive the attention it needs to obtain the answer I seek.

Comment: If you get a good answer here you might consider editing the canonical Question/Answer and closing this one as a duplicate. [Necromancer x 52 :)]

Comment: Additionally, I'm not sure molding someone else's question to extend itself to also cover my question is the best thing to do. I suppose there's an argument both ways, but I'm generally opposed to making someone else's question extend itself beyond what the asker was originally asking. He or she marked an answer as correct which does not cover my question, so clearly the asker had a different question than I have now.

Comment: The other question asks "*After a Git rebase, **and in other circumstances**...*"

Comment: Real question is, Who's They?

Comment: @Bondolin, I don't know what you mean. "They" is "them" and "we" is "us". [Here's my full answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63911630/4561887)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1__63FIOqgQ

Comment: @Bondolin, ahh...a music joke :). I see.

Answer (score 5):

When a conflict occurs, the rule that applies in all situations is :

- `ours`/`us` is the state of the current `HEAD` (the active commit)
- `theirs`/`them` is the state of the other side (the commit being merged, the commit being cherry-picked/rebased, or in your case the "reverse" of the commit you want to revert)

---

Some extra clarifications in the case of a `rebase` (answering @GabrielStaples' comment) :

if you are on `my/branch`, and you run `git rebase other/branch`, `git` will checkout the head commit of `other/branch` and start replaying some commits on top.

If a conflict occurs, since the checked out commit comes from `other/branch`, `ours` will roughly represent `other/branch`, and `theirs` will be `my/branch`.

This part is contrary to the intuition "`ours` should be my changes", but it fits the above description : at the time of the conflict, the checked out commit is `ours`, the other side (the commit being replayed) is `theirs`.

Comment: I don't think this is correct: `When you rebase, us refers the upstream branch, and them is the branch you're moving about. It's a bit counter-intuitive in case of a rebase.` https://stackoverflow.com/a/21025695/4561887. Therefore, `git rebase HEAD~3` means that `us` is `HEAD~3` and `them` is `HEAD`, which is the exact opposite of what your answer states. This is because from `git`'s perspective (I think?) it's actually just cherry-picking the downstream commits, so it has checked out `HEAD~3` so it is now its active `HEAD`, & then it goes on to cherry-pick the downstream commits one-at-time.

Comment: You gave the explanation in the second part of your comment, I edited my answer to highlight how the `ours`/`theirs` rule applies when in the case of a rebase.

Comment: About rebase, it _is_ correct. When you are rebasing, the `base branch` is what is on `HEAD` (hence, us)... and what you are rebasing will be `the other branch`.  http://ezconflict.com/en/conflictsse12.html#x53-890001.7 (**disclaimer**: my material, no cookies, no tracking, no monetization)

Comment: I've upvoted your answer, referenced it and expounded upon it in my answer covering all 4 cases here now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025314/who-is-us-and-who-is-them-according-to-git/63911630#63911630

Comment: @eftshift0, your link seems to have a tag on it (`#x53-890001.7`), but it's not correctly jumping to any spot on the page. Which part of that page would you like me to focus on? (Recommendation: I highly recommend you take a look at using [Github pages](https://pages.github.com/) for personal code websites--you can write in markdown--I'm setting up my own too).

Answer (score 4):

Although this is already answered pretty well, there's one more way to look at it all.  That's the way that Git itself looks at it.  All four operations—cherry-pick, merge, rebase, and revert—use the same machinery, and the `--ours` and `--theirs` flags to `git checkout`, and the `-X ours` and `-X theirs` extended-options, wind up referring to the same things, using the same internal code.  I like to refer to this machinery as *merge as a verb*, because we first get introduced to it through `git merge`, when merge must do a real merge.

#### The merge case

When doing a real merge, the terms make sense.  We start with what can be illustrated this way:

```
          I--J   <-- ourbranch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- theirbranch
```

Here, the name `ourbranch` selects commit `J`, which is our commit on our branch (one of two such commits in this case, though the number of commits that are exclusively on our own branch need only be *at least* 1 to force a real merge).  The name `theirbranch` selects commit `L`, which is their commit on their branch (again one of two, with at least one commit being necessary here).

What Git does in order to do this merging—to *merge as a verb* some set of files—is, for each file in all three commits `H`, `J`, and `L`, compare the file in `H` vs that in `J` to see what *we* changed, and compare the file in `H` vs that in `L` to see what *they* changed.  Then Git combines these two sets of changes, applying the combined changes to whatever is in `H`.

Commit `H` is the *merge base* commit, commit `J` is the "ours" commit, and commit `L` is the "theirs" commit.  Any *difference*, whether it's a new file "added by us", or a file "deleted by them", or whatever, is with respect to commit `H`.

In order to run the merge through the merge machinery, Git does a slightly-optimized-in-advance version of the following:

1. Setup:

   - read merge base commit (`H`) into index at slot 1
   - read `ours` commit (`HEAD` = `J`) into index at slot 2
   - read `theirs` commit (`L`) into index at slot 3
2. Identify "same files".  Note that steps 2 and 3 repeat for every file.

   - if there's a file named *F* in all three slots, it's the same file
   - otherwise, if there's anything in slot 1, try to guess about renames, which will tie a merge base file in slot 1 to an ours or theirs file of a *different name* that's in slot 2 and/or slot 3; if no file can be found to call a rename, the ours and/or theirs side deleted this file; these cases may also lead to high level conflict such as rename/modify or rename/delete, where we declare a conflict and move on without doing step 3
   - otherwise (nothing in slot 1, but something in slots 2 and 3) we have an add/add conflict: declare this particular file to be in conflict, and move on without doing step 3
3. Short circuit easy cases, and do the hard cases with a low-level merge:

   - if the blob hash IDs in slots 1, 2, and 3 all match, all three copies are the same; use any of them
   - if the blob hash ID in slot 1 matches that in 2 or 3, someone didn't change the file and someone did; use the changed file, i.e., take the file that's *different*
   - otherwise, all three slots differ: do a changed-block-of-lines by changed-block, low-level merge

     - if there's a merge conflict during the low level merge, `-X ours` or `-X theirs` means "resolve the conflict using ours/theirs" where ours is whatever is in slot 2 and theirs is whatever is in slot 3
     - note that this means wherever there is *no* conflict, e.g., only one "side" changed line 42, the `-X` extended option does not apply at all, and we take the modification, regardless of whether is ours or theirs

At the end of this process, any fully resolved file is moved back to its normal slot-zero position, with the slot 1, 2, and 3 entries being removed.  Any unresolved file is left with all three index slots occupied (in delete conflicts and add/add conflicts, some slots are empty, but *some* nonzero stage number slot is in use, which marks the file as being conflicted).

#### Hence the *to merge* or *merge as a verb* operates in Git's index

All of the action above happens in Git's index, with the side effect of leaving updated files in your work-tree.  If there are low-level conflicts, your work-tree files are marked up with the conflict markers and the various sections from lines corresponding to the copies of the files that are in index slots 1 (merge base), 2 (ours), or 3 (theirs).

Ultimately it always boils down to that same equation: 1 = merge base, 2 = ours, 3 = theirs.  This holds true even when the command that loads the index is not `git merge`.

#### Cherry-pick and revert use the merge machinery

When we run `git cherry-pick`, we have a commit graph that looks like this:

```
...--P--C--...
   \
    ...--H   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
```

The letters `P` and `C` here stand in for any parent-and-child pair of commits.  `C` can even be a merge commit, as long as we use the `-m` option to specify *which parent* to use.  (There's no real constraint on where the three commits live in the graph: I've drawn it with `H` a child of some commit that comes before `P`, but it can be after the `P-C` pair, as in `...-E-P-C-F-G-H` for instance, or there may be no relationship at all between the `P-C` and `H` commits, if you have multiple disjoint subgraphs.)

When we run:

```
git cherry-pick <hash-of-C>
```

Git will locate commit `P` on its own, using the parent link from `C` back to `P`.  `P` now acts as the merge base, and is read into index slot 1.  `C` acts as the `--theirs` commit, and is read into index slot 3.  Our current commit `H` is the `--ours` commit, and is read into index slot 2.  The merge machinery runs now, so "our" commit is `HEAD` and "their" commit is commit `C`, with the merge base—which shows up if we set `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3`, or if we use `git mergetool` to run a merge tool—being commit `P`.

When we run:

```
git revert <hash-of-C>
```

the same thing happens, except this time, commit `C` is the merge base in slot 1, and commit `P` is the `--theirs` commit in slot 3.  The `--ours` commit in slot 2 is from `HEAD` as usual.

Note that if you use cherry-pick or revert on a range of commits:

```
git cherry-pick stop..start
```

the cherry-picking works one commit at a time using the topologically older commits first, while the reverting works one commit at a time using the topologically newer commits first.  That is, given:

```
...--C--D--E--...
 \
  H   <-- HEAD
```

a `git cherry-pick C..E` copies `D` first, then `E`, but a `git revert C..E` reverts `E` first, then `D`.  (Commit `C` does not come into play because the two-dot syntax excludes the commits reachable from the left side of the two-dot expression.  See [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) for more.)

#### Rebase is repeated cherry-picking

The rebase command works by running `git cherry-pick` repeatedly, *after* using `git checkout --detach` or `git switch --detach` to go into *detached HEAD* mode.  (Technically it now just does this internally; in the old days, some of the shell script based version of `git rebase` really did use `git checkout`, though with a hash ID which always went to detached mode anyway.)

When we run `git rebase`, we start with something like this:

```
       C--D--E   <-- ourbranch (HEAD)
      /
...--B--F--G--H   <-- theirbranch
```

We run:

```
git checkout ourbranch   # if needed - the above says we already did that
git rebase theirbranch   # or, git rebase --onto <target> <upstream>
```

The first—well, *second*—thing this does is enter detached HEAD mode, with the HEAD commit being the commit we selected with our `--onto` argument.  If we did not use a separate `--onto` flag and argument, the `--onto` is from the one argument we did give, in this case, `theirbranch`.  If we did not use a separate *`upstream`* argument, the one argument we gave—in this case `theirbranch`—is used for both purposes.

Git also (first, which is why the above is second) lists out the raw hash IDs of each commit that is to be copied.  This list is much more complicated than it seems at first blush, but if we ignore the extra complications, it's basically the result of:

```
git rev-list --topo-order --reverse <hash-of-upstream>..HEAD
```

which in this case is the hash IDs of commits `C`, `D`, and `E`: the three commits that are reachable from `ourbranch` that are not also reachable from `theirbranch`.

With `git rebase` having generated this list and gone into detached-HEAD mode, what we have now looks like this:

```
       C--D--E   <-- ourbranch
      /
...--B--F--G--H   <-- theirbranch, HEAD
```

Now Git runs one `git cherry-pick`.  Its argument is the hash ID of commit `C`, the first commit to be copied.  If we look above at how cherry-pick works, we see that this is a merge-as-a-verb operation, with the merge base being the parent of `C`, i.e., commit `B`, the current or `--ours` commit being commit `H`, and the to-be-copied or `--theirs` commit being commit `C`.  So that's why ours and theirs seem reversed.

Once this cherry-pick operation is *complete*, however, we now have:

```
       C--D--E   <-- ourbranch
      /
...--B--F--G--H   <-- theirbranch
               \
                C'  <-- HEAD
```

Git now proceeds to copy commit `D` with `git cherry-pick`.  The merge base is now commit `C`, the `--ours` commit is commit `C'`, and the `--theirs` commit is `D`.  This means that *both the ours and theirs commits are ours*, but this time the "ours" commit is one we just built a few seconds (or milliseconds) ago!

It's based on existing commit `H`, which is theirs, but it's commit `C'`, which is ours.  If we get any merge conflicts, they're no doubt a result of being based on `H`, perhaps including some sort of conflict resolution we performed manually in order to make `C'`.  But, quite literally, *all three input commits are ours*.  Index slot #1 is from commit `C`, index slot #2 is from commit `C'`, and index slot #3 is from commit `D`.

Once we have this all done, our picture is now:

```
       C--D--E   <-- ourbranch
      /
...--B--F--G--H   <-- theirbranch
               \
                C'-D'  <-- HEAD
```

Git now runs `git cherry-pick` on the hash of commit `E`.  The merge base is commit `D`, and the ours and theirs commits are `D'` and `E` respectively.  So once again, during rebase, all three commits are ours—though merge conflicts are probably a result of building on `H`.

When the last cherry-pick is done, Git finishes the rebase by yanking the *name* `ourbranch` off old commit `E` and pasting it on to new commit `E'`:

```
       C--D--E   [abandoned]
      /
...--B--F--G--H   <-- theirbranch
               \
                C'-D'-E'  <-- ourbranch (HEAD)
```

We are now back in the normal attached-head mode of working, and because `git log` starts where we are now—at commit `E'`—and works backwards, which never visits original commit `C`, it seems as though we've somehow modified the original three commits.  We have not: they are still there, in our repository, available through the special pseudo-ref `ORIG_HEAD` and available via our reflogs.  We can get them back for at least 30 days by default, after which `git gc` will feel free to reap them and *then* they'll really be gone.  (Well, as long as we didn't `git push` them to some *other* Git repository that's still keeping them.)

Comment: This looks like a really great answer. I look forward to studying it when I get a chance. Thanks for adding it.

Comment: I red the whole thing. Thank you. You must have contributed to the `git` source code to gain this in-depth knowledge? This is very useful info. for me too: "We can get them back for at least 30 days by default, after which `git gc` will feel free to reap them and then they'll really be gone." I never knew how long git would leave abandoned HEADS/commits around.

Comment: The key takeaway for me here regarding `git revert` is, I think, that if you have a linear tree `...A--B--C--D(HEAD)`, with `D` being your current `HEAD`, & you do a `git revert B`, then `B`, the very commit you are trying to revert, becomes the current merge-base, or Slot 1 in this "merge", and Slot 2, or "ours", becomes `D`/`HEAD`, and Slot 3, or "theirs", becomes `A`, or the parent of the commit being reverted, correct? Then, the low-level "merge" is carried out, resulting in applying all changes from `B..D`, as well as all changes from `B..A`, thereby reverting `B`, correct? This is hard.

Comment: Please see my updated "Results and Conclusion" section [of my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63911358/4561887) and tell me if I've got it all straight.

Comment: I have actually contributed (recently, not much though). You do seem to have it straight now. As for how long "abandoned" commits stick around: it's really under control of Git's *reflogs*. The reflog entries keep commits reachable. Running `git gc` runs, among other things, `git reflog expire` with the expiration times set by your GC time settings. This is where the 30 and 90 day default values come from (see the `git config` documentation as well). Once the reflog entries have expired and the commits are truly unreachable, [continued]

Comment: Once expired, a packed object can be ejected from a pack via `git repack`, and a loose object can be removed via `git prune`. Since `git gc` runs both of those (at various intervals) the now-unprotected commits become *unsafe* at this point, but when they actually go away is much more random since the gc process depends on accumulation in the `.git` subdirectories. It might trigger quickly, or it might take months.

Comment: And yes, the gritty details, way down in the bottom levels of Git, are hard. :-) The overall theory and ideas are pretty reasonable but the implementation is full of hacks, compromises, and pragmatic but debatable decisions.

Answer (score 2):

### Summary

Jump to the very bottom for the results and conclusion.

### Details:

Regarding:

> Then `git status` shows the following conflicts:
>
> ```bash
> deleted by them: path/to/file1.h
> both modified:   path/to/file2.h
> deleted by them: path/to/file1.cpp
> deleted by them: path/to/test_file1.cpp
> added by us:     path/to/file3.h
> deleted by them: path/to/file4.h
> added by us:     path/to/file5.h
> ```

I did some experimenting, and observed the following.

First, I manually resolved only the conflicts in the **both modified** file, `path/to/file2.h`, as normal for any rebase or merge conflict. I then added all files and finished the revert:

```bash
git add -A
git revert --continue
```

Next, I observed that all files marked with **deleted by them**, *as well as* all files marked with **added by us**, *were present / in existence on my file system.* So, the revert deleted none of them. Next, I wanted to know: which commit created these files? To see this, run the following ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13598028/4561887)):

```bash
git log --diff-filter=A -- path/to/file
```

This shows the `git log commit_hash` for just the one single `commit_hash` which created this file. I did this *one-at-a-time* for each file which was **deleted by them** or **added by us**:

```bash
git log --diff-filter=A -- path/to/file1.h        # added by the commit I reverted
git log --diff-filter=A -- path/to/file1.cpp      # added by the commit I reverted
git log --diff-filter=A -- path/to/test_file1.cpp # added by the commit I reverted
git log --diff-filter=A -- path/to/file3.h        # added by a later commit
git log --diff-filter=A -- path/to/file4.h        # added by the commit I reverted
git log --diff-filter=A -- path/to/file5.h        # added by a later commit
```

I found that 4 of the files, as indicated above, were added by the commit I reverted. *Note, this means they were added by the commit `some_commit_hash` itself, NOT by the revert commit which was created when I ran `git revert some_commit_hash`.* So, why did they still exist if I reverted that commit? Well, it turns out, a later commit, which we will call `later_commit_hash`, which happened AFTER `some_commit_hash`, touched all 6 of those files, modifying 4 of them and creating 2 of them.

Let's group the above files by groups of **deleted by them** vs **added by us**:

```bash
# deleted by them:
path/to/file1.h
path/to/file1.cpp
path/to/test_file1.cpp
path/to/file4.h

# added by us:
path/to/file3.h
path/to/file5.h
```

Now indicate which file was added by which commit:

```bash
# deleted by them / added by the commit I reverted (`some_commit_hash`)
path/to/file1.h
path/to/file1.cpp
path/to/test_file1.cpp
path/to/file4.h

# added by us / added by a later commit (`later_commit_hash`)
path/to/file3.h
path/to/file5.h
```

So, you can see that **deleted by them** files were added by the commit I reverted, which means that reverting that commit will delete those files! So, `them` refers to the commit being reverted, `some_commit_hash`, while `us` refers to the remaining commits at `HEAD`.

The conflict was that `later_commit_hash` touched those 4 "deleted by them" files, so the `git revert some_commit_hash` wasn't allowed to delete them. And, the 2 "added by us" files did NOT exist prior to `some_commit_hash`, so the conflict was that they shouldn't have existed after the revert, but they did, because they were created by `later_commit_hash`.

The solution I did is I manually deleted all those 6 files:

```bash
rm path/to/file1.h
rm path/to/file1.cpp
rm path/to/test_file1.cpp
rm path/to/file3.h
rm path/to/file4.h
rm path/to/file5.h
```

then I committed this change as a new commit:

```bash
git add -A
git commit
```

However, I *could have* instead reset back to the location prior to the revert commit and reverted `later_commit_hash` first, followed by reverting `some_commit_hash` second, effectively rolling these changes back in order, like this:

```bash
git reset --hard HEAD~  # WARNING! DESTRUCTIVE COMMAND! BE CAREFUL.
git revert later_commit_hash
git revert some_commit_hash
# should result in no conflicts during both of those reverts now
```

### Results and Conclusions:

In either case, to answer my own question:

During `git revert some_commit_hash`:

1. **"us"** = the currently-checked out commit (ie: `HEAD`) at the time you type and run `git revert some_commit_hash`, and:
2. **"them"** = the (inverse or opposite of?) the commit you are reverting; ie: it is some ephemeral commit which is the opposite of `some_commit_hash`, in order to undo `some_commit_hash`'s changes, assuming you run the command `git revert some_commit_hash`.

---

Update 7 Jan. 2020: yes, this does indeed seem to be it. Here's my comment I just left underneath [this other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63915268/4561887). My comment seems to correlate with the above observation perfectly:

> The key takeaway for me here regarding `git revert` is, I think, that if you have a linear tree `...A--B--C--D(HEAD)`, with `D` being your current `HEAD`, & you do a `git revert B`, then `B`, the very commit you are trying to revert, becomes the current merge-base, or Slot 1 in this "merge", and Slot 2, or "ours", becomes `D`/`HEAD`, and Slot 3, or "theirs", becomes `A`, or the parent of the commit being reverted, correct? Then, the low-level "merge" is carried out, resulting in applying all changes from `B..D`, as well as all changes from `B..A`, thereby reverting `B`, correct? This is hard.

So, that means this "ephemeral commit which is the opposite of `some_commit_hash`" is really just the inverse diff, or a diff in the direction of *from* `some_commit_hash` you are reverting *to* its parent commit. Now, you have a low-level git merge going on under the hood, where the merge-base is `some_commit_hash` to revert, "ours"/"us" is `HEAD`, and "theirs"/"them" is the parent of `some_commit_hash`, AKA: `some_commit_hash~`. As git does this low-level merge, the diff from `some_commit_hash` to `HEAD` (ie: the equivalent of `git diff some_commit_hash..HEAD`) captures all your new content, and the diff from `some_commit_hash` to its parent (ie: the equivalent of `git diff some_commit_hash..some_commit_hash~`) captures the *reverse of* the changes done by commit `some_commit_hash`, *thereby reverting this commit!*

If I've got this all straight, it all makes perfect sense now!

---

<s>I'm still struggling a bit with this concept but that's the gist of it. The exact mechanics of how revert works would really clarify things here I think. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63908177/4561887) may offer some more insight, but I don't understand it.</s>

I've also just added an answer to here to clarify "us" and "them" **for all 4 git operations I can think of** where this may happen: `git merge`, `git cherry-pick`, `git rebase`, and `git revert`: [Who is "us" and who is "them" according to Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025314/who-is-us-and-who-is-them-according-to-git/63911630#63911630)

---

(Notes to self):

Need to take a look at: http://ezconflict.com/en/conflictsse12.html#x53-890001.7

Comment: What does `git show --name-status some_commit_hash` say about the 2 files that show as `added by us`?

Comment: @eftshift0, they are not present at all, because they were added by `later_commit_hash`, which came after `some_commit_hash`.

Comment: When I do `git show --name-status later_commit_hash`, however, I see: `R100    path/to/file3_old_name.h       path/to/file3.h` and `R100    path/to/file5_old_name.h       path/to/file5.h`, showing they were each renamed (I don't know what `R100` means exactly though).

Comment: The r100 means that the content didn't change. Ok. Let me digest this whole thing. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Well... `revert` is a very special situation. So, think of a normal merge, with the common ancestor and everything, the whole package, right? Now, the whole thing works the same like a merge **except** (and it's a big except) that the merge engine *forces* `the common ancestor` to be the revision you are trying to revert, and `the other branch` is the *parent* of that revision.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you're saying, as I really think you're on to something here, but I can't understand what you mean exactly. Something is different about this revert situation though, and I think my answer is close but doesn't quite nail it yet either.

Comment: Are you familiar with how a merge is carried out? Like, `the common ancestor` and the 2 tips? If you are, then this is just a simple merge, your branch is your branch, and the common ancestor is _fixed_ to the revision you are reverting, the other branch is its parent. Try to chart that in your head. If you are not familiar with those concepts, go to the same site I linked before and check the section related to the _3-sided coin_.

Comment: Yeah I'm not familiar with how a merge _really_ works under-the-hood. I see your link here (http://ezconflict.com/en/conflictsse12.html#x53-890001.7). I'll check out out.

Comment: Are you seeing this conflict on an open project? I would _really_ like to see what's going on.

Comment: And it _really_ doesn't go into detail about how the merge works.... it at least tells you how the 3 things that are considered for a merge are.... _and_ it begs you to use _diff3_ (which won't make a difference to you.... you are dealing with tree conflicts and I haven't started on that section... coming later).

Comment: `Are you seeing this conflict on an open project? I would really like to see what's going on.` No, sorry, it's a closed project I can't share.